# Java generic Integer data vs primitive int data

Tags: java, integer, int

I know that in **Java** we can use *generic data types* for various reasons. However, in terms of **data storage**. If a primitive **int** in Java can store up to *2,147,483,647* signed values, does this same storage capacity apply for the Integer generic type? Also, does the data type chosen in a program affect the runtime in any way? Or does it more so affect the space-time complexity of a program? My main question is that if I stick with a data type that is rather small but appropriate for my programs needs, than will it by any means help my program run faster?

Comment: As per javadocs *The Integer class wraps a value of the primitive type int in an object.*  If you want bigger use BigInteger

Comment: This might answer your main question about speed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double

Comment: This is a similar question but Java specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155035/which-of-the-following-is-the-fastest-data-type-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the limitations are still there.

You shouldn't treat `Integer` like this magical object, all it is is an object that holds an `int` called `value`. So, without auto-boxing and unboxing, you could technically create your own `Integer` wrapper class. What to take away is `Integer` is pretty much the exact same as `int`, except it's an object.

About your main question about the speed, `Integer` is just a *tiny bit* slower, but I don't think you should worry about it. It's only slower because `Objects` need to be allocated in the heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same limitations apply.

You can see the source of the Integer class here:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java

Line 840 shows that an Integer is backed by a simple `int`:

```
private final int value;
```

So whatever restrictions an `int` has, an `Integer` also has.